# Firebase Analytics DebugView doesn't work on iOS (Unity) when ConsentType.AnalyticsStorage = ConsentStatus.Denied

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics DebugView doesn't work on iOS (Unity) when ConsentType.AnalyticsStorage = ConsentStatus.Denied, but when I make it ConsentStatus.Granted, I can see the events in Firebase's DebugView.

I am running my app in an iPhone, with the arguments: -FIRDebugEnabled -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

I can't have AnalyticsStorage granted because it'd violate the privacy policy. But it looks like no events make it to Firebase when I deny it.

Although I still see all the events in XCode console, as if it were sending them.

Here's my Unity code:

```cs
FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true); // Collection enabled
FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); // I can't track the events from the same user in different sessions.

// These are device identification properties, they are granted by default, we MUST disable them.
FirebaseAnalytics.SetConsent(new Dictionary<ConsentType, ConsentStatus> {
    { ConsentType.AdStorage, ConsentStatus.Denied },
    { ConsentType.AnalyticsStorage, ConsentStatus.Denied }, // Changing this make it work.
});

FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty(FirebaseAnalytics.UserPropertyAllowAdPersonalizationSignals, "false");
```

Is this a bug in Firebase or am I misunderstanding how Firebase should work? I just want to avoid having Firebase identify users across different sessions.

Answer (score 1):

according to provided information:
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/app-consent?platform=ios

> You can indicate whether consent has been granted for Analytics and Ads identifiers.

So if you are not providing access to sending data via consent you can't receive it in DebugView.

> I can't have AnalyticsStorage granted because it'd violate the privacy policy.

DebugView provides ability to see event data on development devices/build. It's only for internal test within your company. Organic user shouldn't have ability to use dev build, so users privacy policy can't be violated in that case.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but that debug data doesn't show up in my Analytics dashboard either.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?hl=en&platform=ios#view_events_in_the_dashboard) data in Analytics dashboard updates periodically throughout the day. So receive immediate respond like in DebugView is impossible